# How to record in jMeter from some inbetween page (Not from Starting page)

Tags: jmeter, action-recording

I want to start recording from the 3rd page of my application as I have recorded scripts for first 2 pages.
One option is : I can record from beginning and delete the scripts of first 2 pages so that i can get the recorded scripts of 3rd page but could you please suggest if there is any option to start recording from 3rd page ?

Note : 1st and 2nd page is related to my login page and 3rd page is navigation page after login.

Comment: you can disable http request by right click on it. so disable first 2 pages request and make enable 3rd so it will automatic run 3rd direct.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [Blazemeter's Chrome Extension](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU8ICxiprKAhXLGI4KHeE4BmoQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fblazemeter-the-load-testi%2Fmbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNGAgTkXd1GXqSLZm9btpLBttZESEg) to record my performance test scripts for Jmeter.

It is a simple plugin for Google Chrome using will you will be able to record what you browser in Chrome as you are browsing it. What even better is that it will also record the required sessions, cookies and and variable/field input hence making it possible for you to easily prepare a test plan for web pages that require human interaction or authentication. Once you are done with recording your script, you can download the jmx file and use it to edit/execute your performance tests in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

According to fact that the first 2 pages are login ones, you have also to take care of user session which will be created after login procedure on those pages, in order to later be able to navigate to page 3 (this can be done by Cookie Manager component where you'll define valid session cookies manually).

And yes, I think you should better stick to the approach you've described since it doesn't require much work to be done, but just delete 1st and 2nd pages you've visited during recording the script.

Of course you can also play with "URL patterns to include" option of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) but it gives you less flexibility as your script will grow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways are using browser extensions:

1. If you're using JMeter's proxy look for something like [QuickProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/quickproxy/) Firefox addon. Using it you can switch browser between using proxy and direct connection in a single click.
2. Use [JMeter Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/BlazeMeter?hl=en) extension - can be easier as it doesn't require any proxy configuration.